# How to read all columns as str with Polars on Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

How to read all columns as string with polars at rust?
That's my code

`let df = CsvReader::from_path(filecsv)?.has_header(true).finish()?; Ok(df)`

It read some data as int64, but I want to read all columns (whenever they're calls) as string. How can I do it?

Comment: Looks like [`with_dtypes()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.CsvReader.html#method.with_dtypes) is what you want.

Comment: It depends of schema, but I don't know a schema of all columns =(

Comment: You don't need all columns, only the columns you want to change their type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,it can only convert some(not all) fields to `str` and you need to add the `smartstring` crate.

```
use polars::datatypes::DataType::Utf8;
use polars::prelude::*;
use smartstring::SmartString;
use std::sync::Arc;
fn main() {
    let mut schema = Schema::new();
    schema.with_column(SmartString::from("some_columns"), Utf8);
    let df_csv = CsvReader::from_path("some_input.csv")
        .unwrap()
        .infer_schema(None)
        .has_header(true)
        .with_dtypes(Some(Arc::new(schema)))
        .finish()
        .unwrap();
    println!("{}", df_csv);
}
```

=================================================

After further experimentation, I find another way. This requires using the `csv` crate. First, you need read the `CSV headers` using `rdr.headers()` and map them into an iterator. Then, a schema is created by using `from_iter`.

```rust
use polars::datatypes::DataType::Utf8;
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path("some_input.csv").unwrap();

    let column_names = rdr.headers().unwrap().iter().map(|item| Field::new(item,Utf8));
    let schema = Schema::from_iter(column_names);
    let df_csv = CsvReader::from_path("some_input.csv")
        .unwrap()
        .infer_schema(None)
        .has_header(true)
        .with_dtypes(Some(Arc::new(schema)))
        .finish()
        .unwrap();
    println!("{}", df_csv);
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it requires reading the file twice, which can be inefficient. Unfortunately, I haven't found a suitable API to avoid this limitation at the moment.

Maybe there are better solutions...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all columns to be strings, you can simply use [`infer_schema(Some(0))`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.CsvReader.html#method.infer_schema). This will use 0 rows to infer the schema, which results in all columns being “inferred” as strings (the default, most general type).

For `LazyCsvReader` the corresponding method would be [`with_infer_schema_length`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.LazyCsvReader.html#method.with_infer_schema_length).